# How can I note transformation step?

Tags: math-mode, align

I currently have this:

[image]

with this code:

```
\begin{align}
    0     &\stackrel{!}{=} (d_{P,f}^2)'\\
          &= -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p f'(x) + \left (f(x)^2 \right )'\\
          &\overset{\mathclap{\normalfont\mbox{Chain rule}}}{=} 
             -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p f'(x) + 2 f(x) \cdot f'(x)\\
          &= -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p (2ax+b) + ((ax^2+bx+c)^2)'
\end{align}
```

Instead of `\overset{\mathclap{\normalfont\mbox{Chain rule}}}{=}`, I've also tryed `\stackrel{\text{chain rule}}{=}`:

[image]

The best I could come up with is `\overset{\mathclap{\tiny\mbox{chain rule}}}{=}`:

[image]

But it still does not look satisfying. Is it possible to make a line break within "chain rule"? Do you have a better idea for this kind of annotation?

Comment: Just use text to say *chain rule*. It's way more healthier. `\intertext` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A combination of `\substack` -- a macro provided by the `amsmath` package -- and `\mathclap` (provided by the `mathtools` package) may be able to deliver what you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
0 &\stackrel{!}{=} (d_{P,f}^2)'\\
  &= -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p f'(x) + \bigl(f(x)^2 \bigr)'\\
  &\stackrel{\mathclap{\substack{\text{Chain}\\\text{Rule}}}}{=} 
     -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p f'(x) + 2 f(x) \cdot f'(x) \\
  &= -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p (2ax+b) + ((ax^2+bx+c)^2)'
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Typically these things are set as comments (on the right) of the actual structure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    0 &\stackrel{!}{=} (d_{P,f}^2)'\\
      &= -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p f'(x) + \bigl(f(x)^2 \bigr)'\\
      &= -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p f'(x) + 2 f(x) \cdot f'(x) \rlap{\hspace*{2em}(Chain rule)} \\
      &= -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p (2ax+b) + ((ax^2+bx+c)^2)'
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The fact that the comment is set in `\rlap` automatically turns it into text mode, but also does not affect the horizontal placement of the entire structure

Comment: Thanks for informing me how this is usually done (+1)! At the moment, I'm not sure if I want to use this or Micos solution. As he gave me what I was looking for, I accepted his solution.

Answer (score 4):

Or simply add another (left-aligned) column

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    0 &\stackrel{!}{=} (d_{P,f}^2)'\\
      &= -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p f'(x) + \bigl(f(x)^2 \bigr)'\\
      &= -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p f'(x) + 2 f(x) \cdot f'(x) && \text{(Chain rule)} \\
     &= -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p (2ax+b) + ((ax^2+bx+c)^2)'
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you intention was making `Chain rule` as narrow as possible...

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
    0     &\stackrel{!}{=} (d_{P,f}^2)'\\
          &= -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p f'(x) + \left (f(x)^2 \right )'\\
          &\overset{\mathclap{\begin{array}{c}\mbox{\tiny Chain}\\[-6pt] \mbox{\tiny rule}\end{array}}}{=} -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p f'(x) + 2 f(x) \cdot f'(x)\\
          &= -2 x_p + 2x -2y_p (2ax+b) + ((ax^2+bx+c)^2)'
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, one can correct also vertical spacing between 2nd and 3rd line, but I am not sure if this your wish.